# ELBO - Jensen Inequality

Tags: maximum-likelihood, variational-bayes

In the ELBO derivation:

[image]

Why do we need the inequality? Why not use the exact equation of the log of expectation? In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iL1c1KmYPM0) at minute 34, she says if the expectation is before the log, it is easier to sample from it. What is the reason? What's wrong with sampling first, and then do the log?

Comment: I prefer the ELBO derivation without the Jensen's inequality

Answer (score 0):

ELBO is a quantity used to approximate the log marginal likelihood of observed data, after applying Jensen's inequality to the log likelihood leading to the fact that maximizing the ELBO with respect to the parameters of $p$ is equivalent to minimizing the KL-divergence from $p_{\theta }(\cdot |x)$ to $q_{\phi }(\cdot |x)$. Without this approximation, sampling before taking the log can readily introduce high variance for the expectation, making the optimization much less stable. By taking the log before sampling helps avoid this issue since the log function often produces much smaller values for the ratio of two distributions, providing more stable and efficient gradients during optimization.

Comment: Thanks cinch, is there a proof that E(log(..)) is better than log(E(...)) ? Is it intuitive? Why smaller values are better than large values? Can't you simply adjust the learning rate to make the steps smaller?

Comment: It's not about smaller values being inherently "better" than larger values; it's about stability in optimization. Large values in computations can lead to numerical instability, the intuition behind this lies in taking the logarithm often transforms products and quotients (which can lead to numerical instability) into sums and subtractions, respectively, making the computations more stable. Adjusting the learning rate can indeed help with the convergence of optimization, but the choice of this lower bound objective function is  a principled approach ensuring stability and convergence.